# How can I define regular expression and to make sure that it contains a certain character?

Tags: regex, regex-lookarounds

I have to define a Membership ID which is a string of 3 characters which can have lower/upper case letters and digits.

For instance AA2 and 2AA or  A22 are valid regular expressions.  It does not matter the position, I need to make sure there is at least one digit in the string.

The current expression is this `([a-z]|[A-Z]|[0-9]){3}` . What should I add as a "condition" to look for a digit?

Thank you in advance,
Liviu

Answer (score 1):

You can use a lookahead like this:

```
^(?=[A-Za-z]*[0-9])[A-Za-z0-9]{3}$
```

`(?=[A-Za-z]*[0-9])` is a positive lookahead to assert we have at least a digit after 0 or more alphabets.

[Read more about lookarounds in regex](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html)

Answer (score 1):

You can separate conditions:
`cond.1` and `cond.2` would be true only if the both are true that's means that at the `cond.1` we check if string contains 3 chars and in the `cond.2` we check if it contains a number:

```
var a=/([a-zA-Z]|[0-9]){3}/g
var b=/([0-9]){1,2}/g
if(a && b){
    //return true only if the word contains 3 characters and including at least a number 
}
```

Comment: While this code snippet may solve the question, [including an explanation](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/114762/explaining-entirely-code-based-answers) really helps to improve the quality of your post. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, and those people might not know the reasons for your code suggestion.